# Meaning of command1 | command2 is?

Tags: command-line

Please give the answer for what purpose we use this command only single '**|**'

Please tell me.

Comment: This is most definitely not the first time this has been asked. 

Comment: @Artur Meinild - yes, I agree - I’ve answered but flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is used to *pipe* the output of command 1 into the input for command 2.

For example, `ls | grep .jpg` would pipe the output from `ls` into `grep` and only show files with .jpg in the title.